# Retrieve data without _source field:

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I'm new in elasticsearch, I am doing a match all query and it retrieves the data in this way but only I want the data in retrieved in the _source, how can I do it? any idea abot it?

```
    {
  "took": 4,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 107271,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "sku_index",
        "_type": "po",
        "_id": "0",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "loc": "ZZZ",
          "part": "PPP",
          "order_qty": "16",
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "sku_index",
        "_type": "po",
        "_id": "14",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "loc": "ZZZ",
          "part": "XXX",
          "order_qty": "7",
        },
{
            "_index": "sku_index",
            "_type": "po",
            "_id": "14",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
              "loc": "ZZZ",
              "part": "ZZZ",
              "order_qty": "7",
            }
          }
      .......
```

I wnat something like this:

```
      [{
          "loc": "ZZZ",
          "part": "PPP",
          "order_qty": "16",
        },
       {
          "loc": "ZZZ",
          "part": "XXX",
          "order_qty": "16",
        },
      {
          "loc": "ZZZ",
          "part": "ZZZ",
          "order_qty": "7",
        }
      ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way is to do [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/search-request-source-filtering.html), by adding to your query

```
"_source": {
        "includes": [ "loc", "part", "order_qty" ],
        "excludes": [ "not_needed_field" ]
},
```

Another way, if your fields are [stored](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/search-request-stored-fields.html) (which not always the case and often not recommended, due to additional space requirements.

> By default, field values are indexed to make them searchable, but they
>   are not stored. This means that the field can be queried, but the
>   original field value cannot be retrieved.

So you need to add to your query:

```
"stored_fields" : ["loc", "part", "order_qty"]
```

Comment: I tried with `{
  "query": {
    "_source": {
      "includes": [
        "obj1.*",
        "obj2.*"
      ],
      "excludes": [
        "*.description"
      ]
    },
    "match_all": {}
  }
}` but not works

Comment: And `GET /sku_index/po/_search
{
    "stored_fields" : ["loc", "part"]
}`not works neither

Comment: did you replace obj1. with desired field names?

Comment: Yes I useed this:, `GET /sku_index/po/_search
{
  "query": {
    "_source": {
      "includes": [
        "part.*",
        "order_qty.*"
      ],
      "excludes": [
        "*.loc"
      ]
    },
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
`  is correct?

Comment: also, as i mentioned, stored fields most likely will not work for you, especially if you re using default settings

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134480/discussion-between-mysterion-and-joan-triay).